# PHP unserialize variable

Tags: php, serialization

Good afternoon everyone,

Is any simple way to unserialize that type of data and put everyone into Array()

```
$variable= "'Body Style'=>'SEDAN 4 DOOR';'CD Player'=>'PRESENT';'Color'=>'GRAY';'Engine Size'=>'3.0L V6 FI  F';'Air Bags'=>'4';'Radio'=>'PRESENT';'Tape Deck'=>'N/A';'Estimated Repair Cost'=>'5518';'ACV'=>'6122';'Driver Airbag'=>'INTACT';'Passenger Airbag'=>'INTACT';'Left Side Airbag'=>'INTACT';'Right Side Airbag'=>'INTACT';'VIN Status'=>'OK';'Interior Color'=>'GRAY';'Airbag'=>'INTACT';'KeyFob'=>'PRESENT';";
```

without using `explode()`, `foreach()` and then `preg_match` functions?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use those specific functions?

Comment: I in no way endorse this: `$json = '{' . str_replace(["'", '=>', ';'], ['"', ':',  ','], rtrim($variable, ';') ) . '}';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is any simple way to unserialize that type of data and put everyone into Array()
>   without using using explode(), foreach() and then preg_match functions?

Yes, you can use `preg_match_all()`.

```
if (preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'=>'(.*?)';/", $variable, $matches)) {
    $result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    print_r($result);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Body Style] => SEDAN 4 DOOR
    [CD Player] => PRESENT
    [Color] => GRAY
    [Engine Size] => 3.0L V6 FI  F
    [Air Bags] => 4
    [Radio] => PRESENT
    [Tape Deck] => N/A
    [Estimated Repair Cost] => 5518
    [ACV] => 6122
    [Driver Airbag] => INTACT
    [Passenger Airbag] => INTACT
    [Left Side Airbag] => INTACT
    [Right Side Airbag] => INTACT
    [VIN Status] => OK
    [Interior Color] => GRAY
    [Airbag] => INTACT
    [KeyFob] => PRESENT
)
```

The advantage of this approach is it works even if any key or value contains semicolons such as `Body;Style` or `SEDAN;4 DOOR` which would make the `explode()` approach fail.

See https://3v4l.org/YuuZM

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval` to assign the contents of `$variable` to another variable as an array, like this:

```
$variable= "'Body Style'=>'SEDAN 4 DOOR';'CD Player'=>'PRESENT';'Color'=>'GRAY';'Engine Size'=>'3.0L V6 FI  F';'Air Bags'=>'4';'Radio'=>'PRESENT';'Tape Deck'=>'N/A';'Estimated Repair Cost'=>'5518';'ACV'=>'6122';'Driver Airbag'=>'INTACT';'Passenger Airbag'=>'INTACT';'Left Side Airbag'=>'INTACT';'Right Side Airbag'=>'INTACT';'VIN Status'=>'OK';'Interior Color'=>'GRAY';'Airbag'=>'INTACT';'KeyFob'=>'PRESENT';";
$variable = str_replace(';', ',', $variable);
eval("\$array = [$variable];");
print_r($array);
```

The use of `eval`, however, is greatly discouraged. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

I'm assuming you're getting the contents of `$variable` from somewhere else. Is there any particular reason you have the data in that format and not in json, for example?

EDIT: I just realized the code won't work as is, because the values of the array are separated by semicolons and not by colons. You need to replace the semicolons with colons first. I've updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: I think he wants the string parsed into an array with multiple elements in key value pairs. This just puts the whole string into a key. Which you don't need eval for.